# piThreadCreate error after call function

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wiringpi

I receive an error after the call TerminalFrame::start();. What I doing wrong?

> TerminalMain.cpp|223|error: cannot call member function ‘int
>   TerminalFrame::start()’ without object|

```
void TerminalFrame::start()
{
StaticText1->SetLabel(wNFC);
}

PI_THREAD (startNfc)
{

     TerminalFrame::start();

  return NULL ;
}

piThreadCreate (startNfc) ;
```

Comment: this function must be `static` in order to be called without an object (e.g. `TerminalFrame::start()`) but without this it should be called `someTerminalFrame.start()`.

Comment: TerminalFrame.start(); TerminalMain.cpp|230|error: expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token|

Comment: Sure, it's because `TerminalFrame` looks to be a class name. Do you have an object of this class or maybe a reference to it ? Or consider changing your function to `static void TerminalFrame::start`.

Comment: I cant use static -  TerminalMain.h|186|error: invalid use of member ‘TerminalFrame::StaticText1’ in static member function|

Comment: and it's again because `StaticText1` is not a `static` member.

Comment: It turns out - my task is done can not be?  ))

Answer (score 1):

To call a member function like `ClassName::foo()` the function must be `static`.

If the function isn't static, you must create an object first like:

```
ClassName var;
var.foo();
```

Comment: TerminalFrame its a wxFrame. I cant create it again

Comment: If you have already created it, you must have a handle to it already that you can use.